# How to embed Google Maps on a field on Odoo through a new Widget?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, odoo, odoo-10

I'am new on Odoo and I'm learning how to create a new widget, at first time I want embed a Google Maps screen with my form. To start, I've created two groups inside a `<record><form>`, the first group I showed some data (it's ok) and on second group I want show a Google Maps screen (it's a problem). I've created a module called `vz.visit`.

**1. First try**

Create `google_maps_widget.js`, `teste.xml` and `google_maps_widget.xml`.

**views.xml**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="vz_visit_create_form_view_2">
  <field name="name">vz.visit.form</field>
  <field name="model">vz.visit</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Registro de Visita">
      <sheet>
        <group>

          <!-- DATA GROUP: It's OK -->
          <group>
            <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
            <field name="partner_id"/>
            <field name="description"/>
            <field name="date_start"/>
            <field name="date_end"/>
            <field name="duration"/>
            <field name="location"/>
          </group>

          <!-- MAP GROUP: Not works -->
          <group>
            <field name="google_map_partner" widget="vz_google_map" nolabel="1"/>
          </group>

        </group>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

**google_maps_widget.js**

```
odoo.define('vz_visit.FieldMap', function(require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var form_common = require('web.form_common');

var FieldMap = form_common.AbstractField.extend({
    template: 'FieldMap',
    start: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, {
            center: {lat:-26.22947, lng:-52.671561},
            zoom: 10,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
        });
    }
});

core.form_widget_registry.add('vz_google_map',FieldMap);

return {
    FieldMap : FieldMap,
};

});
```

**google_maps_widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="FieldMap">
        <div class="vz_gmap"></div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

**teste.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/vz_visit/static/src/js/google_maps_widget.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Result: The page ins't loaded and the errors are showed.

*Errors:*

- Dialog: `ReferenceError: Google is not defined.`
- Console: `ReferenceError: Google is not defined.`

**2. Second try**

Idea: using a callback function to load google maps on src script. Editing the follow two files:

**teste.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/vz_visit/static/src/js/google_maps_widget.js"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]&callback=initMap"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

**google_maps_widget.js**

```
odoo.define('vz_visit.FieldMap', function(require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var form_common = require('web.form_common');

var FieldMap = form_common.AbstractField.extend({
    template: 'FieldMap',
    start: function() {
        var self = this;

        var map;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('vz_google_map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 10
            }
        );
      }
    }
});

core.form_widget_registry.add('vz_google_map',FieldMap);

return {
    FieldMap : FieldMap,
};

});
```

Result: The page is loaded but the map isn't showed.

[image]

*Errors:*

- Console: `Could not get content for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY defined in bundle web.assets_beckend`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's Developer Console?

Comment: Yes, 1. First try errors: https://imgur.com/a/rT9nmMA

Comment: 2. Second try errors: https://imgur.com/a/UWozp7V

Comment: @travisw errors above

Comment: Please provide the errors as **text** (not images); and in your question (not the comments), .

Comment: @geocodezip updated.